# Sonar Analysis configuration via Maven, Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I developed a maven project. For code analysis I want to use the sonarqube. I did sonar cube configuration in my pom.xml. But I want my sonar analysis should only run when auto build is executed by jenkins on any commit to SCM. I don't want to run sonar analysis when developer create a build on his/her local machine. For dev machine I will use sonarlint. How can I do this?

Comment: Implement that in the pipeline code in Jenkinsfile...?

Comment: This question is too broad and pretty straightforward without any problem which is having some errors. and I think there are good examples in medium regarding how to set-up Jenkins jobs or pipelines in Jenkins to achieve this.